# Having trouble with time.sleep (python)

Tags: python, pygame

This is what I have done to import time

```
import pygame, random, time
from time import sleep
```

When it comes to the point in my code:

```
time.sleep(4)
```

I Get the error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sleep'

any ideas guys?

Comment: Why are you importing `time`, and then importing `sleep` from `time`?

Comment: Something bad might have happened with `time.sleep` inbetween. Something like `del time.sleep`

Comment: try: pygame.time.delay

Comment: Don't use `sleep()`, `delay()` etc. It stops your animation if you have it.

Comment: Actually, sleep() can be important to keep your process from pegging the CPU.  I'd think this was clear, now that almost all common operating systems supports multitasking.  It used to be common on MS-DOS, but that's long dead.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you imported sleep directly from time. This means you can just call:

```
sleep(4)
```

instead of

```
time.sleep(4)
```

Another good solution would be to omit the code importing sleep specifically, so you get:

```
import pygame, random, time
#the "from time import sleep" line is deleted

time.sleep(4)
```